# PostgreSQL; superuser; how to get list of passwords of users which is in star form in database, to send the passwords to users?

Tags: sql, postgresql, passwords

I am superuser in postgreSQL, and created passwords for users randomly, and forgot to save from command line. Now, all the passwords of the users that I CREATED are in star form. how can I get those passwords to send to users.
Or if I can't recover that list,or if there is another way to change the all users passwords.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The passwords are hashed with a one-way hash. There is no way you can get the clear text passwords.

The only option you have is to set a new password using `\password` (in `psql`) or `alter user` (in any other SQL client).

Comment: Is there any way to get the command line history? or if I can change passwords of all the users?

Comment: ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD new_password; will this command work to change the password of each user?